# Public class members in PIMPL

Tags: c++, coding-style, api-design, libraries

I'm attempting to use the PIMPL idiom. This is my public header file in `include/foo.h`:

```cpp
class FooPrivate;

class Foo {
public:
        Foo();
        ~Foo();

private:
        FooPrivate* p_impl;
};
```

The private class is defined in: `src/foo_private.h` and used throughout `src/*.cpp`:

```cpp
class FooPrivate {
public:
        ...
private:
        ...
};
```

My question is, what are the reasons to distinguish `public:` or `private:` members and functions in `FooPrivate` since the entire class is private? This is from the perspective of distributing `foo.h` and `libfoo.so` to end users who will use it.

I figure that paying attention to public and private members would enforce correct coding practices, i.e. making me think about exposing an API to use around my private code.

On the other hand, by having all public members in `FooPrivate`, I would have an easier time writing unit tests for it, and also pass it around more easily in my code without having to think about APIs, accessors, etc. Also, the whole thing is private so the end user won't be impacted by this sloppiness, right?

Which would you prefer?

Note that I'm still a beginner at C++ so I could be wrong about my assumptions.

*update*

Based on the replies, I have settled for continuing to use public/private when appropriate.

The advantage of PIMPL is that I was able to hide the googletest friend test macros in the private header file, without exposing that in the public one, e.g.

```cpp
#ifdef UNIT_TESTS
#include <gtest/gtest_prod.h>
#endif

class FooPrivate {
public:
        ...
private:
#ifdef UNIT_TESTS
        FRIEND_TEST(FooPrivate, Test1)
#endif
        ...
};
```

This way I can write whatever tests I need.

Now whether or not testing private members is a good idea seems like a whole other can of worms.

Comment: *"by having all public members in `FooPrivate`, I would have an easier time writing unit tests for it, and also pass it around more easily in my code without having to think about APIs, accessors, etc"* This argument is valid for all classes. However, you wouldnt make everything public in every class.

Comment: This is a good point, and both you and Bart said the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, what are the reasons to distinguish public: or private: members and functions in `FooPrivate` since the entire class is private? This is from the perspective of distributing `foo.h` and `libfoo.so` to end users who will use it.

From the perspective of users of `Foo`, there is no reason at all to even have functions in `FooPrivate`, let alone private functions or private data members.

On the other hand, from the perspective of the *author* of `FooPrivate`, it should be considered just the same as any other class, with private sections to protect its implementation details from accidental interference. The fact that the primary user is a PIMPL wrapper class (`Foo`) is just incidental here.

You might choose to provide a richer interface from `FooPrivate` for testing reasons, but that is still no reason to make all its innards public.